# Agora IO cloud recording resourceId is null getting 400 response

Tags: rest, api, agora.io

I am implementing Agora cloud recording via RESTful API. I have already contacted with agora support and with my appid and they confirmed that recording service is enable. But when I am trying in postman to get the resourceId I always get resourceId is null and 400 response. I have stydied tons of documents but did not get the solution. 
prereuistics done: 
1) cname : channel name is correct
2) uid: I have used a uid and tired also automatic uid after join the channel
3)appid: appid is definatly correct

App url :
https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/244e87editedlittlebit1b645/cloud_recording/acquire
method: POST
Auth: basic
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

response body: 
{
    "cname":"11493098",
    "uid": "2398640696",
    "clientRequest":{}
}

Basic Auth with REST API credintials (customer ID as username, customer certificate as password)

response body: 
{
    "cname":"11493098",
    "uid": "2398640696",
    "clientRequest":{}
}

response:
{
    "resourceId": "",
    "code": 400
}

{
    "resourceId": "",
    "code": 400
}
I expect the resource ID which is needed to start the recording but I am always getting resouceID is null and code 400(which means input wrong)
If anyone tell me the cause It will be very much help for me. I appreciate any clue.

Comment: are you able to authenticate using the customerID (appId) and customerCertificate (token)?

Comment: Thanks @Hermes. I have got the responseId. I have contacted with vcube support and they said try again and I got it.

Comment: @Hermes how to check thta?

Comment: Follow the instructions on the Quick Start Guide to ensure you have enabled Cloud Recording on your account https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_rest?platform=RESTful#project-setup

Comment: HI @CodeLover I have same issue. Can you tell me what you did to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Your request seems fine, can you please check if your cloud recording is enabled or not. if not then enable cloud recording from your app's cloud recording menu. 
You can follow these steps:
https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_rest#enable-cloud-recording

Thank you